# What methods and properties are provided for use through scripting for standard InDesign panels?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I’m able to get a reference to, for instance, the “Scripts” panel; but, although its constructor’s name is `'Panel'`, it doesn’t seem to have the `show` and `hide` methods like panels created through scripting, or the `window` property, etc.:

```
var scriptsPanel = app.panels.item('$ID/Scripts')    
scriptsPanel.window // → “Object does not support the property or method 'window'”
scriptsPanel.show(); // → “scriptsPanel.show is not a function”
```

It does have some of script-created Panels’ properties, though:

```
scriptsPanel.visible // → true or false
```

**What are standard panels’ methods and properties**, and where are they documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several places where the DOM objects are documented, Adobe's official way would be to use the ExtendScript Toolkit to browse the objects and their methods and properties (in the ExtendScript Toolkit go to Help > Object Model Viewer).

Having said that, most ExtendScript users seem to find this browser cumbersome to use, so there are a few pages online that document the InDesign Object Model.

I personally use and prefer the [InDesign ExtendScript API](https://www.indesignjs.de) by Gregor Fellenz, but another popular one is Jongware's [Adobe InDesign CS6 (8.0) Object Model JS](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/) viewer (that seems to be not updated anymore for more recent versions of InDesign). I prefer Gregor Fellenz' page, because it has a search function and I find it a bit easier to navigate.

The properties and methods of a panel in InDesign you could find [here](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#Panel.html). Note that there is also the panel object of the ScriptUI, which is documented [here](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#PanelSUI.html). ScriptUI is Adobe's script language to create user interfaces. So the two panel objects have different methods and properties, that's why one of them didn't have the `show()` method.

As you have noted, this leads to the somewhat confusing fact that there are two different types of objects with the same constructor name `Panel`. However, there is no real ambiguity in the use of them, as the panels that are native to InDesign's UI are always children of the `app` object, whereas the panels that you create in a script via ScriptUI are always children of other ScriptUI objects. The same goes for other DOM/ScriptUI name pairs, such as `window`.

Note that the fact that there is a `panel` object in InDesign means that there is also a `panels` collection object, which has properties and methods to work with a collection of panels. This `panels` object is documented [here](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#Panels.html).

Comment: Thank you! So there are two classes with the same name? That’s incredibly confusing. I regularly use Jongware and Fellenz’s docs, but I didn’t think of looking for that.

Comment: Yes, that can be confusing indeed, I added another paragraph with a bit more specific explanation.